# How do I incorporate my Python methods in the Kivy code?

Tags: python, oop, kivy

I coded a small program in Python that randomly picks between two categories and subset the dataframe accordingly. Once done, it picks a row and presents the question and a potential choice. The question and the choice are found in the row of the dataframe under two different columns. So far, it's working well; the problem is when I tried to incorporate this with kivy.

I don't understand how the sequence of actions in taken place. Basically, I want to be able to include the question and the choice on the screen via the kivy file. So far, I'm able to show them, but it looks like the value from the question doesn't match the value from the choice column. My intuition tells me that my kivy file runs the "Choosing_category" twice instead of just running it once and taking the appropriate outputs. Does anyone knows how I can solve this issue?

Here is what I have so far:

tryapp.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
kivy.require('1.11.1')

class QuestionWindows(Screen):
    def __init__(self,  **kwargs):
        super(QuestionWindows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.prob = ''
        self.word = ''
        self.choice1 = ''
        self.word = ''
        self.df = pd.DataFrame()

    def _get_df(self):
        df = pd.DataFrame([['new', 'What is you favorite color?', 'blue?', 'blue', 0,0,0,0,0],
                           ['familiar', 'What is your favorite fruit?', 'apple?', 'apple', 0,0,0,0,0],
                           ['new', 'What is your favorite vegetable?', 'carrot?', 'carrot',0,0,0,0,0]],
                          columns=['state', 'questions', 'choice1', 'answer', 'cnt', 'count_correct', 'error_count', 'total_error', 'total_correct'])
        return df

    def choosing_category(self):
        # Loading the dataframe
        self.df = self._get_df()

        # Generating the category for which the question/answer will be sampled from
        self.prob = np.random.choice(['new', 'familiar'], 1, p=[0.7, 0.3])
        # Dealing with the condition on whether the state 'familiar' is not found in the data set
        if self.prob not in self.df['state'].values:
            self.prob = ['new']
            self.prob = self.prob
        else:
            self.prob = self.prob
        # Making sure to present a question/answer that hasn't been presented recently
        if len(self.df[(self.df['state'] == self.prob[0]) & (self.df['cnt'] == 0)]) > 0:
            self.tmp_df = self.df[(self.df['state'] == self.prob[0]) & (self.df['cnt'] == 0)]

        elif len(self.df[(self.df['state'] == prob)]) > 0:
            self.tmp_df = self.df[(self.df['state'] == prob)]
        else:
            self.prob = ['familiar']
            self.tmp_df = self.df[(self.df['state'] == self.prob) & (self.df['cnt'] == 0)]

        # Getting the question from the temporary dataframe
        self.word = np.random.choice(self.tmp_df['questions'])

        # Getting the choice from the question that was previously selected
        self.choice1 = self.df.loc[self.tmp_df[self.tmp_df['questions'] == self.word].index, "choice1"].values
        return str(self.word), str(self.choice1[0])


class QuestionsApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        self.question_page = QuestionWindows()
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(self.question_page)
        return self.screen_manager


if __name__ == "__main__":

    tryapp = QuestionsApp()
    tryapp.run()
```

questions.kv

```
    <SmoothButton@Button>:
    background_color: (0.0, 0.4, 0.95, 1)
    background_normal: ''
    font_size: 20

<QuestionButton@Button>:
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    background_normal: ''
    back_color: (0.0, 0.4, 0.95, 1)
    border_radius: [2,2,22,22]
    color: (0.0, 0.4, 0.95, 1)
    bold: True
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.back_color
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: self.border_radius

<QuestionWindows>
    #id: question_page
    name: "question_page"
    FloatLayout:
        QuestionButton:
            id: question
            text: root.choosing_category()[0]
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.1, 'y': 0.77}
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.17
            back_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            background_normal: ''
            font_size: 20
            background_down: ''
        SmoothButton:
            id: choice1
            text: root.choosing_category()[1]
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.1, 'y': 0.27}
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.1
```

Comment: Once you have chosen your question in `QuestionWindows`, you can set the `QuestionButton` text with `self.ids.question.text = "This is a Question?"`. Similar for the choices.

Comment: Thanks @JohnAnderson! I really appreciate. For some reason, my entire program doesn't start so it's not taken into consideration. However, I didn't get an error either, so it must be because there is something else wrong.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you are loading your `kivyfile.kv`. You can either call `Builder.load_file('kivyfile.kv')` or change its name to `questions.kv`.

Comment: Good observation pointing that out! Carelessly I named the file ```kivyfile.kv``` here so people will be able to identify it properly, but the actual name is questions.kv.
The naming convention is important with kivy and I should have been more careful.. I'll change it right away.

Comment: Your code runs for me (after defining `SmoothButton`). Is there anything else missing from your posted code?

Comment: You have some code in your `build()` method that doesn't seem to make sense. It should just be four lines: `self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()`, `self.question_page = QuestionWindows()`, `self.screen_manager.add_widget(self.question_page)`, and `return self.screen_manager`.

Comment: I fixed the build method() and the SmoothButton. To make that I didn't forget anything else, I copied the code that is here into PyCharm. 
The app runs, but I can't get a question to display aside from the message "'The question will go here!!!'". Where exactly did you include self.ids.question.text = "This is a Question?" ?

Comment: Can you display a random question from the dataframe to be presented on the top button?

Comment: Such code could go into an `on_enter()` method of `QuestionWindows` class. Something like: ` self.ids.question.text = self.choosing_question()`. But that method raises an exception for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JohnAnderson! You gave me a great idea and I'm almost out of the wood. I modified the code above, but now I'm running into a new issue. I'm able to display the question and the answer, but unfortunately, they don't match. I think it's because the function is ran twice from the kivy file, but I'm not entirely sure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the `choosing_category()` method getting called twice. A good way to fix that is to use the `on_enter()` method as I suggested. You can modify your `QuestionWindows` class as:

```
class QuestionWindows(Screen):
    word = StringProperty('')
    choice1 = StringProperty('')
.
.
.

    def choosing_category(self):
        # Loading the dataframe
        self.df = self._get_df()
        .
        .
        .
        # Getting the question from the temporary dataframe
        self.word = np.random.choice(self.tmp_df['questions'])

        # Getting the choice from the question that was previously selected
        # Note the added [0] at the end of this line
        self.choice1 = self.df.loc[self.tmp_df[self.tmp_df['questions'] == self.word].index, "choice1"].values[0]
        # return str(self.word), str(self.choice1[0])


    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.choosing_category()
```

This adds two properties to the `QuestionWindows` class that are updated by the `choosing_categroy()` method, and can be referenced within the `kv`:

```
<QuestionWindows>:
    #id: question_page
    name: "question_page"
    FloatLayout:
        QuestionButton:
            id: question
            text: root.word
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.1, 'y': 0.77}
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.17
            back_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            background_normal: ''
            font_size: 20
            background_down: ''
        SmoothButton:
            id: choice1
            text: root.choice1
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.1, 'y': 0.27}
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.1
```

An advantage of this approach is that you can simply call `choosing_category()` and the question and choice will update.

Comment: You just solved my problem! Thanks so much @JohnAnderson!